# Strange query results on different collation

Tags: sql-server, collation, sql-like

During development I came across a strange scenario using DD with `Macedonian_FYROM_90_CI_AS` Collation.

```
declare @test_table  table
( numbers varchar(20) collate Macedonian_FYROM_90_CI_AS )

insert into @test_table values('0711110000000') 
insert into @test_table values('0711110000001')
insert into @test_table values('0711110000002')

select * from @test_table WHERE numbers like '071111%00000'
```

It should return `0711110000000`, but result from query is null.

I try the same test on another DB using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` Collation and query returns `0711110000000`.

Have anyone faced with the same problem, or can explain this?

Comment: Strange. `select * from @test_table WHERE numbers like N'071111%00000'` works.

Comment: If no-one comes up with an explanation as to why this is expected behaviour might be worth reporting as a possible bug on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback)

Comment: @MartinSmith he should run sp_helpdb and tell us the collation of his DB which get also to child tables - by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange behavior indeed. I've noticed it with other collations as well (Slovenian_100_CI_AS, Macedonian_FYROM_100_CI_AS, Finnish_Swedish_100_CI_AS ...) though some work as expected (Slovenian_CI_AS) on the same test set.

I decided to submit feedback to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/703959/search-with-like-not-working-as-expected-with-collation-slovenian-100-ci-as).

Comment: +1 Can you update this answer when they respond with an explanation?

Comment: @MartinSmith The issue has been closed as fixed in SQL Server 2012. They aren't going to fix it in older versions because of backwards compatibility concerns. Microsoft CSS should be contacted if a hotfix is required.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
select * from test_table WHERE numbers like '071111%00000'  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS
```